# Maintaining MobX objects synchronized with database

Tags: javascript, real-time, mobx

I am using MobX with my React app, to manage my global state. Basically I am mirroring the structure of my backend data (a relational DB) and fetching data as needed.

Currently I have the following structure:

```js
class Model {
    @observable id
    @observable propA = 0

    constructor(doc) {
        this.id = doc.id
        this.propA = doc.propA
    }

    @action
    update = (doc) => {
        this.propA = doc.propA
    }

    @computed
    get computedProp() {
        return this.propA * 2
    }
}

class Store {
    records = observable.map()

    @action
    fetchOne = async (id) => {
        const doc = await fetch(url + id)
        const model = new Model(doc)
        this.records.set(id, model)
    }

    getOne = copmutedFn((id) => {
        if (!this.records.has(id)) {
            this.fetchOne(id)
        }

        return this.records.get(id)
    })
}
```

The `computedFn` function comes from mobx-utils, and is basically a computed that accepts parameters.

I keep all the records in the store `records` property to maintain reference between different parts of the app.

What I now have to do is keep these records up to date with my database, and I plan to do it with a fixed interval polling method.

However I don't want to refetch every record I have stored, some of the records may not be being observed anymore and I want to only fetch the ones that are currently needed on the app.

Is there a way for me to look into, for example, the `records` prop and check which ids are being observed and which are not?

Is there some other structure may allow such finer control without any hacking into the MobX internals, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [mobx atoms](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/extending.html#creating-observable-data-structures-and-reactions), basically it is a way to create your own data structures.

It has two callbacks that you might use: `onBecomeObserved` and `onBecomeUnobserved`. They will notify you when something starts and stops observing your data structure.

Comment: I didn't know about mobx atoms! I'll keep them in mind! They seem to work, but generate a lot of boilerplate. In the end I ended up using the `now` observable from mobx-utils to make the `getOne` computed recompute every so often and added an update call on it.